# How to fix MyPy [return-value] error when type is actually correct

Tags: python, django, mypy, python-typing, django-ninja

I am using Django-Ninja + MyPy and I get this error that type it received **tuple[int, dict[str, str]]"** is not correct as it doesn't match one of the **tuple[int, None] | tuple[int, DetailType]** types but it is exactly as second type. Because in other parts of code it can figure out correctly it has **"detail"** as key. But as soon as I use **Union[...]** it somehow cannot look recursively?

```
apps/users/views.py:106: error: Incompatible return value type (got "tuple[int, Message]", expected "tuple[int, None] | tuple[int, DetailType]")  [return-value]
```

This is how my types look like:

```
DetailType = TypedDict("DetailType", {"detail": str})
MessageType = tuple[int, DetailType]
NoContentType = tuple[int, None]
```

And this is complete code where mypy is returning error:

```
@post("me/password/change/", response={204: None, 401: Message}, url_name="users_me_password_change")
def change_password(request: HttpRequest, data: ChangePasswordRequest) -> Union[NoContentType, MessageType]: <<< THIS IS RETURN TYPE
    user = request.user
    if not user.check_password(data.password):
        return 401, {"detail": "Password is incorrect."} <<< IN THIS LINE IS MYPY ERROR
    user.set_password(data.new_password)
    user.save()
    return 204, None
```

Comment: I don't think it's *your* return type declaration that's causing the problem, it's the `@post` decorator.  Note that its `response` parameter is specifying a type of `Message` for result code 401, and that's exactly what the error message is saying the actual type is, even though you aren't using that type in your function definition.

Comment: I don't think so because on other views there is `200: Message` and `MessageType` as return and everything works. Message is Schema which has "detail" as key and string as value also. In this case I think also other views should fail with MyPy.